# Why do XML Namespaces usually start with http://...?

Tags: wpf, xml

For example, the WPF namespace is:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

If I define my own namespace, should it also start with http? Isn't http **misleading**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are there XAML namespaces that are URLS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390033/why-are-there-xaml-namespaces-that-are-urls)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [W3C Document defining XML Namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) says ([quoting](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#sec-namespaces)) :

> Definition: An XML namespace is
>   identified by a URI reference
>   [RFC3986]

And [RFC 3986](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) says (quoting) :

> **1.1.1.  Generic Syntax**
>
> Each URI begins with a scheme name,
>   as defined in Section 3.1, that
>   refers to a specification for
>   assigning identifiers within that
>   scheme.

So I guess using http:// is what's closest to the standard -- as HTTP is the most common scheme used on the net.

In addition, as there can be only one owner for a domain name, it allows each company to use it's URL in its namespaces.

Answer (score 7):

Namespaces doesn't have any meaning in their value, except for that value to be unique to avoid nameclashing. This is why you see a lot of companies putting in the URL for their own website as the namespace. URLs serve the same purpose, to be unique. Over the years it's just become good practice to use an URL, because if everyone does that, no nameclashing should occur :)

Comment: Additionally, it has become a convention to document the namespace at the given URL — although the above example doesn't follow that convention.

Answer (score 5):

Another common way instead of using a URL starting with `http://` is to use a [**Uniform Resource Name**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name) whose format is defined by [RFC2141](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2141).

Such namespace identifiers are e.g. used by ODF (OpenDocument Format):

```
urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0
urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0
urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

From [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_namespaces.asp) at W3Schools:

"The namespace URI is not used by the parser to look up information.  The purpose is to give the namespace a unique name. However, often companies use the namespace as a pointer to a web page containing namespace information.  Try to go to http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/."

Answer (score 1):

It is a reliable way to create a readable globally unique identifier. It may or may not be to a valid URL with more information.

Comment: That's the point - the namespace is intended to remove any ambiguity --> it has to be unique. Domain names are unique - "yourcompany.com" only exists exactly once. But the namespace "url" typically has no actual real representation, typically no document or page exists at that URL

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is why the "http" prefix is used. For example, the domain name without "http" would also be unique.