# Why are there XAML namespaces that are URLS?

Tags: xaml, namespaces

In Silverlight/WPF xaml at the top of the code you have your namespace/import type declarations. I can easily understand how these declarations can point to an assembly so that the types etc can be loaded from it. What I don't understand (and what I haven't really thought about up to now) is how these namespaces work when they point to a url, e.g.

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit
```

Looking at this URL gives me an error so doesn't tell me anything.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's [an attribute you can use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx) in the code of your referenced assembly that maps a Uri to your code namespaces:

```
[XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://yournamespace/", "Your.Assembly.Namespace")]
```

You can include multiple of these attributes, typically in your `AssemblyInfo.cs`, allowing multiple code namespaces to be referenced by a single Uri namespace in Xaml.

This makes your namespace declarations more compact (since you can omit the assembly name).  It also allows you some flexibility in reorganizing namespaces in the referenced assembly without breaking your markup.

**EDIT:** for example, if you point Reflector at the `PresentationCore` assembly, you can see attributes such as this at the assembly level:

```
[assembly: 
    XmlnsDefinition( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation"
                   , "System.Windows.Ink") ]
```

This is how the Uri import gets mapped to code namespaces.

Comment: my AssemblyName showing in project properties is `Company.Component` and the namespace in that assembly I'm trying to reference is `Company.Component.Behaviors` but `[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://Behaviors.Component.Company", "Company.Component.Behaviors")]` referenced by a xaml file in the current assembly still fails to be found so the xaml compilation step in the build fails. Also tried adding the optional `AssemblyName="Company.Component"` part to the assembly attribute (with and without the `.exe`)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know they are URLs only out of convention, any unique identifier would do.

If you check HTML doctypes they are exactly the same, as in not actually loading :) For example: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd or http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd

It makes no sense why isn't anything on these URLs though, would be nice to have some actual references...

Comment: They're supposed to be Xml namespace names - which should be a Uri.  There's no requirement for the Uri to actually host any content though.  Since the Uris for xaml references actually map to local code assemblies, there's not really anything meaningful that you could host there.

Comment: @DanPuzey I agree with the idea of "it should be a URI". But URI are not necessary to be staring with http://, that's for browsing with Hypertext Transfer Protocol, which make no sense in xaml

Comment: (Blimey, old thread!)

You are correct, Uri don't have to be HTTP, but equally: we use HTTP for a lot more than just "browsing" and, if you wanted to host a formal schema somewhere online, HTTP is more than likely to be the protocol you'd use to expose it.