# Dynamic C# Method or multiple If-else-if blocks?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a situation where I need to validate if multiple checkboxes are checked in WPF application and run code block accordingly. The only thing that changes with all the iterations of the code block is the file name. Sample code looks like this

```
if(checkbox1.IsChecked == true)
{
    Code(fileName1);
}
if(checkbox2.IsChecked == true)
{
    Code(fileName2);
}
if(checkbox3.IsChecked == true)
{
    Code(fileName3);
}
```

It all looks redundant. And I cannot create a method and pass the file name and checkBox name to it as the checkBox will be passed as a string and IsChecked property will be invalid for a string. Any way to overcome this and make the code look neat ?

Comment: When you say `something == true`, it's the same as `something`. It usually makes it more readable.

Comment: Point noted. But even if I change if(checkbox1.IsChecked == true) to if(checkBox1.IsChecked) it will still throw the same error,no ?

Comment: Yes, they're equivalent statements, just a readability thing.

Comment: If `Code(filename)` will be executed anyway, just make your logic to change the filename and avoid writing "Code" multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to manually link up the checkboxes to strings the same way you have it now, and are just looking for shorter code, you can wrap up the checkboxes into a dictionary, then loop through them:

```
var filesByCheckbox = new Dictionary<CheckBox, string> {
    { checkbox1, filename1 },
    { checkbox2, filename2 },
    { checkbox3, filename3 }
};

foreach (var kvp in filesByCheckbox)
{
    if (kvp.Key.IsChecked)
    {
        Code(kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

This doesn't really improve anything, but it just makes it a little clearer which checkbox is attached to which file so adding to the list is only one line instead of 3.

I'd probably go with Tanner's answer if it works for you.

Comment: When I was implementing your solution, I got another idea. Why not create a method that does all the activity and pass an object of type CheckBox to that method as an argument ? It makes a lot of sense. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the form to use a subclass of `CheckBox`? If so, you could do this:

```
class MyCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        if (IsChecked)
        {
            (do something with FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Then set the value of `FileName` in the form designer. Finally, replace the code from your question with something like this:

```
checkbox1.MyMethod();
checkbox2.MyMethod();
checkbox3.MyMethod();
```

Comment: Looks like this would do it. Will give it a try and report back

Comment: I am a bit of a beginner in C# here and I tried to begin with your proposed solution. I created a new class CustomCheckBox and inherited from CheckBox using CustomCheckBox : CheckBox. Ideally now CustomCheckBox should replicate all the properties of CheckBox isn't it? When I update my XAML and replaced CheckBox with CustomCheckBox, it is throwing an error and it says that CustomCheckBox is not supported in a WPF project. Why would this be happening? CheckBox and CustomCheckBox are similar objects , right?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with WPF, so I don't know the answer to that. This page may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351652/how-to-use-a-c-sharp-custom-subclass-in-xaml However, it may be easier for you to use Joe Enos's solution (or the idea that you thought of while implementing Joe's solution--I think that was a good idea).

Comment: Got what I wanted by creating a method that accepts checkbox as an argument. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to somehow map your checkboxes to the filenames. An easy way would be to use the Tag property:

```
checkbox1.Tag = filename1;
checkbox2.Tag = filename2;
checkbox3.Tag = filename3;
```

Then put yout checkboxes into an array and process that:

```
var checkboxes = new [] { checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3 };

foreach (var checkbox in checkboxes.Where(cb => cb.IsChecked))
{
    Code((string)checkbox.Tag);
}
```