# How to add a custom ListBox in C# xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I had a custom class derived the listbox class. I added a `MyListBox.cs` file in project:

```
namespace WSBSync
{
    class MyListBox : ListBox
    {
        //some new methods and data members by me...
    }
}
```

Following this [How to use a C# custom subclass in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351652/how-to-use-a-c-sharp-custom-subclass-in-xaml), I modified my xaml file namespace like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WSBSync.MySettingWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WSBSync"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
```

and my custom UI here:

```
<local:MyListBox x:Name="sourceListBox" SelectionChanged="mySelectionChanged"/>
```

But I got an error during build: MyListBox doesn't exist in "clr-namespace:WSBSync"  namespace.

I tried clean and rebuild my project, the error is still there.
What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `public class MyListBox : ListBox`