# Is it possible to declare a namespace in code behind

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to declare a namespace like:

```
<Window xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"/>
```

In code behind, e.g. in the constructor.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    // ... here
}
```

Purpose: less verbosity; declare namespaces in one place and use inheritance.

EDIT: I tried adding

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://mycompany/myapp", "clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls")]
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://mycompany/myapp", "myc")]
```

to `AssemblyInfo.cs`
but the build finishes with error "The namespace prefix "myc" is not defined".

So I use the attirbutes in the same project as where the xaml file is.

Comment: `<opinion>`Less verbosity but having to go in another file to know from what namespace an object comes from would be annoying!`</opinion>`

Comment: @Vache: I'd say it depends on the usage. If you have an assembly full of common Xaml components in different (assembly) namespaces, it's convenient to refer to that whole assembly with a single (xml) namespace. Similarly, you can potentially reference multiple assemblies through a single xml namespace if your project is complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, namespaces are part of the [XML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) and have nothing to do with xaml/.Net

If your namespaces were declared in code behind, then your XAML would not be a valid XML document.

Comment: Not true. See my answer in a minute... :)

Comment: Ha! I've actually used that attribute and forgotten about it. Good call +1.

Comment: Maybe not completely true, but XML needs the ns and prefix declaration after all, and my aim was to get rid of that in a central place which is not possible.

Answer (score 8):

There's [an attribute you can use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx) in the code of your referenced assembly that maps a Uri to your code namespaces:

```
[XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://yournamespace/", "Your.Assembly.Namespace")]
```

You can include multiple of these attributes, typically in your `AssemblyInfo.cs`, allowing multiple code namespaces to be referenced by a single Uri namespace in Xaml.

For example, if you point a decompiler at the `PresentationCore` assembly, you can see attributes such as this at the assembly level:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Ink")]
```

This is how the Uri import gets mapped to code namespaces.

(Full disclosure: I have taken this answer from an earlier answer I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390033/why-are-there-xaml-namespaces-that-are-urls) for a similar question.)

Comment: I need the `XmlnsPrefix` attribute as well. See my edit: it doesn't seem to work out of the box.

Comment: I'm not sure what you've done but, once you've added the `XmlnsDefinition` attribute, you still need to declare `xmlns:foo=http://mycompany/myapp` in the root element of your xaml. Have you included that? You don't need `XmlnsPrefix` for this to work.

Comment: Yes, with prefix declaration it works, but my idea was to also declare the prefix and that doesn't seem to work this way.

Comment: You can declare a default prefix for serialization use, but you still have to declare the namespace and prefix in your XAML files.