# How can types be found when xlmns points only to a website?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, namespaces, prism

Consider this namespace definition and usage within the below xaml.  Some namespaces such as inf are pointing to an actual assembly that contains code within a namespace. That's fine, and I understand that.  What I do not understand is how can a namespace that simply points to a website work?  As you can see the prism namespace isn't pointing to any assembly, yet later within the xaml you can see the prism:RegionManager and the intellisense is able to determine the types.  I would have thought that I'd be required to provide the clr-namespace and prism assembly containing that prism functionality.

```
<Window x:Class="PrismDemo.Shell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
        xmlns:inf="clr-namespace:PrismDemo.Infrastructure;assembly=PrismDemo.Infrastructure"
        Title="Shell" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.ToolbarRegion}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.StatusBarRegion}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <TabControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.ContentRegion}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Content.DataContext.Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                    </Style>
                </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </TabControl>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Good question, but it's been asked before, and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5390146/424129

Comment: I see.  I searched in a few ways but I couldn't find that.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: I selected close as duplicate. An extra copy stored off as duplicate could make it easier for people searching to find the answer.

Comment: Makes sense to me.