# Why are the namespaces in xaml or lots of other xml files not reacheable?

Tags: xml, namespaces

When I open up Visual Studio and create a new WPF project there is a XAML document with the following line at start.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
```

When I copy the URIs over to a web browser to look inside the namespace definition it returns the 404 status. If i remove the namespace definitions it throws as first error `The standard namespace is not defined.`

In many other xml files it's equally true that most of the given http URIs in the namespace definitions are not available on the specified adress.

How is this internally working especially in XAML? Where are the namespace definitions located when they are not where the URI shows to?

---

Edit: After posting my question the Topic [Why do XML Namespaces usually start with http://…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232419/why-do-xml-namespaces-usually-start-with-http?rq=1) it explains how the namespace definition is named. But where are they actually coming from in case of XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after searching around for some new keywords brought more informations.

a) Like Quentin already said are the URIs in the just strings to uniquely identify the namespace. They are not mandatory working web adresses.

b) There is a blog entry explaining nicely where the actually connected classes are coming from [here](https://blog.pixelingene.com/2006/10/xmlnsdefinition-for-a-cool-namespace-mapping/)

c) There are some .xsd files from Visual Studio under `<Visual Studio installation directory>\Xml\Schemas`.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are arbitrary strings, not URLs. They are used to identify the namespace, not to describe anything that might be fetched over HTTP. The convention of them looking like HTTP URLs is primarily there to ensure uniqueness (the idea being that you only create a namespace using a domain name you control, so you won't introduce a clash with someone else).

Comment: Ok, so far I see the point but where are the actual definitions of eg. XAMLs presentation namespace?

Comment: There's no information in the XML document that would tell you that. I'd use Google to try and find them.